# How can I combine/serialize such JSON objects by means of Node.js or NPM modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, serialization, node-modules

I would be very grateful if someone suggested how to get such a **JSON**

```
[
  {
    "type": "A_TYPE",
    "value": "foo"
  },
  {
    "type": "A_TYPE",
    "value": "bar"
  },
  {
    "type": "B_TYPE",
    "value": "qux"
  },
  {
    "type": "C_TYPE",
    "value": [
      10000,
      19999
    ],
    "name": "1xxxx"
  }
]
```

from such a **JSON**

```
[
  {
    "type": "A_TYPE",
    "value": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "B_TYPE",
    "value": [
      "qux"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "C_TYPE",
    "value": [
      [
        10000,
        19999
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

In this case, objects with a property like **"type":"A_TYPE"** in which you want to combine **"value":""** can be more than one.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: **I apologize for my poor English. And I would be grateful if you would find and correct my mistakes.**

Comment: `"name": "1xxxx"` where did this come from?

Comment: This JSON contained some company data and I replaced some values with my own to post here.

Answer (score 1):

I made this solution to your question.

```
let arr = [
  {
    "type": "A_TYPE",
    "value": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "B_TYPE",
    "value": [
      "qux"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "C_TYPE",
    "value": [
      [
        10000,
        19999
      ]
    ]
  }
];

let newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].value.length; j++) {
    let value = arr[i].value[j]; // Get value from the object
    let type = arr[i].type;  // Get type from the object

    // New Object to push to the new Array
    let tempObj = {};
    tempObj.type = type;
    tempObj.value = value;
    newArr.push(tempObj);  // Push object to array
  }
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

[Test it here](https://repl.it/@TheNerdGuyLulu/StackOverflow-answer)

Comment: **Thanks for your help! Probably because of the bad English I incorrectly described the situation, I need to get the first JSON from the second, i.e. this code does the opposite.**

Comment: **Sorry terrible formatting error :( Of course you're right. Already correct. Sorry again.**